# How to pass parameters to Ionic modal with the new variant of fromTemplateUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-tabs-app for iPad.
In one of my templates i open an ionicModal by click.
Without Parameters it's all fine.
But now i want to give Parameters to the modal.
I saw an example with the old variant of fromTemplateUrl.
But i have to use the new variant which Returns a promise.

This is the original code of the methods which are calling the modal:

```
$scope.showTypeOfTest = function (type_of_test_id) {
    return $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/type-of-test.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.show();
};
```

Then i tried this to give an ID to the modal, but it doesn't work, because the controller which is bound to the other template by ng-controller is called just after the method fromTemplateUrl was executed and before $scope.modal was set.
How can i pass parameters in this variant?

Here's the code to my own try, which doesn't work:

```
$scope.showTypeOfTest = function (type_of_test_id) {
    $scope.type_of_test_id = type_of_test_id;
    return $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/type-of-test.html', function ($ionicModal) {
        $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });
};
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.show();
};
```

Comment: Which ionic version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 1.3.1.

Comment: Can you explain exact scenario what you want to do? If you want to just pass id then you have to put it in scope like you do in your code and other code will be like origin code. And you can retrieve data by calling {{type_of_test_id}} in model template.

Comment: I have two templates, each one with it's own controller. When i click per example on a button or treeview item in template-1 it opens template-2 modal. The problem is that when i'm i the controller of template-2 i can't see the parameter in $scope. Just when i use the $rootScope it works. Meanwhile i switched to that solution but i hope there is another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attacching data to the scope is working fine to me, look at the snippet, instead if you do not want to attach data to the scope and you are using a controller for the modal, you can use events

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  
  $scope.contacts = [
    { name: 'Gordon Freeman' },
    { name: 'Barney Calhoun' },
    { name: 'Lamarr the Headcrab' },
  ];

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  
  $scope.openModalWithData = function(contact, propagateEvent) {        
    var fullName = contact.name.split(' ')
    var userToEdit = {firstName: fullName[0], lastName: fullName[1]};
    $scope.modal.show();
    if( propagateEvent ) {
      $scope.$broadcast('setEditUser', userToEdit)
    } else {
      $scope.editUser = userToEdit;
    }
  };

})

.controller('ModalController', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.$on('setEditUser', function($event, editUser) {
    alert('setting the user')
     $scope.editUser = editUser;  
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 
    
    <title>Ionic Modal</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Contacts</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-click="openModalWithData(contact, $index == 1)">
          {{contact.name}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
    
    <script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view ng-controller="ModalController as vc">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">Edit Contact</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
              <input ng-model="editUser.firstName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
              <input ng-model="editUser.lastName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Email</span>
              <input ng-model="editUser.email" type="text">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="createContact(newUser)">Save</button>
            
      
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

```
....
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    $rootScope.$broadcast("dataForModal", {some: 'infos'});//be sure to inject the $rootScope
  };
  .....
```

Then inside your modal controller

```
$scope.$on('dataForModal', handleReceivedData);
function handleReceivedData($event, data) {
    //watherever you need to do with data
}
```

Comment: Nice Piece of code, Daniele. But does this work too, when You have two seperate templates and controllers?

Comment: I updated the code, having separated templates should work as well as long you change `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html'` with `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('the/path/to/your/modal.html'`